# Capture request IP Address in Web API Authentication Filter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I would like to capture the IP Address of the client that calls my Web API service.
I am trying to capture that IP address in a custom Authentication Filter that I have created.

Is the request IP address available from the `HttpActionContext` ?

I cannot seem to find it.

Is the Authentication Filter the wrong place where to capture the IP address of the client making the request ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I recently found the following extension method for that:

```cs
public static string GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
    {
        return IPAddress.Parse(((HttpContextBase)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress).ToString();
    }
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_OwinContext"))
    {
        return IPAddress.Parse(((OwinContext)request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"]).Request.RemoteIpAddress).ToString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can now call:

```cs
HttpActionContext.Request.GetClientIpAddress();
```